# Javascript form/textbox/alert

Tags: javascript, jquery

It's my first day working with JavaScript, and I need help on a simple demo. I need to take the value from `class="populateValue"`, and make it fill in the text box and alert when the button is clicked.

Right now it is returning `'[object Object]'` in both text box and alert.

My code is:

```
<section>
    <form>
        <input type="text" id="demoText" />
        <button class="populateValue" value="1234">Populate Value</button>
    </form>
</section>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.populateValue').on('click', function (event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            $('#demoText').val($('.populateValue'))
            alert($('#demoText').val());
        });
    });
</script>
```

Any advice?

Comment: One of the features on jQuery is that many (if not most) of its functions have one version that sets, and with one fewer argument, it gets.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

change this line:

```
$('#demoText').val($('.populateValue').val());
```

Comment: perfect! Care to explain why you need to add the additional .val?

Comment: @user1678151: `$('.populateValue')` is a jQuery object containing the element, `$('.populateValue').val()` is a string containing its value.  `'[object Object]'` is what happens when you try to read an object as a string.

Comment: see comment by @RocketHazmat.

Comment: `$("#demotext").val(this.value)` is even more concise. `this` refers to the object that was clicked, ie the button.